# How to use cloudflare with hostinger.in

Tags: domains, cloudflare

I am using both cloudflare and hostinger now. In domain I updated nameservers to that of cloudflare. I use hostinger to host the domain. After I updated, in hostinger it said

> Your domain is not pointing to our nameservers at the moment, so services such as FTP, File Manager, E-mail (and others) will not work correctly. You can find our nameservers at the "Accounts -> Details" section. Please mind that DNS might take up to 24 hours to propagate when the change is submitted.

But when I update the files in it in FTP, it correctly shows in the website. But when i try to install WordPress, it says its not pointing as above.

Comment: To clarify, is the site working fine when you visit it after going behind Cloudflare? 

Things like MX records will need to be recreated in Cloudflare otherwise services won't work. Whatever it's checking for Wordpress likely isn't set in Cloudflare - but if the site works, then I wouldn't be concerned.